# How can I display all results?

Tags: sql, plsql

My table bellow consist of **different** colour teams of which have *played* another colour and received **points**.

```
   CREATE TABLE COLOURS
   (C_ID VARCHAR2 (4) NOT NULL,
    HC VARCHAR2 (4),
    AC VARCHAR2 (4),
    TOTAL NUMBER (2),
    SCORES NUMBER (2));

  INSERT INTO COLOURS VALUES
  ('C1', 'RED', 'BLUE',8,'');

  INSERT INTO COLOURS VALUES
  ('C2', 'RED', 'BLUE', 9,'');

  INSERT INTO COLOURS VALUES
  ('C3','BLUE', 'RED', 10,'');

  INSERT INTO COLOURS VALUES
  ('C4','BLUE', 'RED', 11,'');
```

Next I have created a function that calculates the total points for the teams:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TOTAL  (i_HC   COLOURS.HC%TYPE)
 RETURN NUMBER              
  IS
v_COLOURS_total     COLOURS.total%TYPE;  

   BEGIN
    SELECT SUM (TOTAL)
    INTO v_COLOURS_total             
    FROM COLOURS            
    WHERE 
HC = i_HC;  

 IF v_COLOURS_total  IS NULL THEN             
  v_COLOURS_total:=0;                   

 END IF;

 RETURN v_COLOURS_total;            

 END;
```

Lastly a procedure to call that function and display the result of each team one by one:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COLOURS_SCORES (dnum VARCHAR2)
   IS                                                     
   W_HC   COLOURS.HC%TYPE;       
   W_C_ID COLOURS.C_ID%TYPE;
   W_TOTAL  COLOURS.TOTAL%TYPE;             
   W_SCORES     NUMBER(2);              
   TOTALSCORES  NUMBER(5,2);    


    CURSOR COLOURS_CURSOR IS            
SELECT HC,C_ID,TOTAL,SCORES 
FROM  COLOURS
    WHERE HC = dnum;
    BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' '||'COLOURS POINTS '||'  '); 

   OPEN COLOURS_CURSOR;

    TOTALSCORES :=TOTAL(dnum);    
     LOOP

FETCH COLOURS_CURSOR INTO W_HC,W_C_ID,W_TOTAL, W_SCORES;
EXIT WHEN COLOURS_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(W_C_ID || '----'|| W_TOTAL ||'  ');


    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---------------------------------------');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(W_HC||' '||'FINAL SCORE = '||TO_CHAR(TOTALSCORES));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---------------------------------------');
    CLOSE COLOURS_CURSOR; 

     END;
```

Now, after execution of the procedure, for example `EXECUTE COLOURS_SCORES ('RED');` 
I get the result of colours:

- If argument is **RED** I get  `(17)`.
- If argument is **BLUE** I get `(21)`.

My question is:

- Is it possible to display the results of **both** teams and **order** it by the **highest total**?
- Or Perhaps, do I need only a ***function*** for this?

> *Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use just open the cursor on a query which will give you this information? Something like:

```
SELECT HC, SUM (TOTAL) as Total
FROM COLOURS            
GROUP BY HC
ORDER BY SUM(TOTAL) DESC
```

With this query there is no need for the function.

### Update

As you want to use the function you could try something like:

```
SELECT HC, C_ID, TOTAL, SCORES, TOTAL(HC) as TOTALSCORES
FROM  COLOURS
ORDER BY TOTAL(HC);
```

I haven't tested this as I'm not near a PC but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated. I would like to see it work as a function :)